# sharepoint user control

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We are currently using outlook and exchange to reserve / book rooms and resources at our company. We set up a mail box for the resource and share the calendar so that others can use it. We are looking at changing to Sharepoint Foundation 2010 to do this with the group calendar. The questions is can sharepoint 2010 control users like outlook? We would need to have two accounts:

1. IT Dept (To add / delete / modify calendars)
2. user (To reserve resources, to view all reserved resources already setup by all
   users, and edit only there own reserves).

I am just wanted to know if it is possible to setup Sharepoint to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is what is sharepoint used for :)
Just be carefull with permissions, but it's pretty easy to set them up.

If your users are already using outlook you should think of connecting outlook wit sharepoint calendar: http://www.outlookexchange.com/articles/jasonsherry/sherry_c24p1.asp

Comment: If we connect Sharepoint to Outlook, does it go though exchange?  Do the resources still need a mailbox to be used in outlook?